# How to link OR-Tools (Python module) on a site in PHP/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, or-tools, pyscript

I am developing a website in PHP with JavaScript. Part of the site consists of solving a timetabling problem which is written as an integer linear optimization problem. I currently have a python program that uses the OR-Tools module for Python running to solve my problem, but I would like to put it online.

I'm wondering how to do this. Here are the ideas I'm thinking of:

- There is an OR-Tools interface written for Node.js. Unfortunately, I don't know Node.js and its use seems incompatible with the current scripts that run on the client side.
- Is it possible to install/upload the OR-Tools module on my host's server, and to communicate my JavaScript with Python (for example with pyScript. Brython does not allow the use of this module because it contains vs).

Do you have any other solutions/tracks for me?

I tested solvers written in JavaScript (jsLPsolver.js and glpk.js), but they do not work on problems of the size of those I have (around 10000 variables).